# How to add a build in function to an ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lotusscript

We are working to extend the [Antlr VB6 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/vb6/VisualBasic6.g4) to cover LotusScript.

LotusScript has a few functions that are alien to VB.
I'm trying to make my grammar understand something like this:

```
x = Inputbox("How Happy are you")
y = Inputbox("Number", "Enter any number", "0")
```

I tried to add grammar:

```
inputboxStmt
   : INPUTBOX WS? argList
   ; 

INPUTBOX
   : I N P U T B O X
   ;
```

Existing definitions from the [vb6 Grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/vb6/VisualBasic6.g4):

```
argList
   : LPAREN (WS? arg (WS? COMMA WS? arg)*)? WS? RPAREN
   ;

arg
   : (OPTIONAL WS)? ((BYVAL | BYREF) WS)? (PARAMARRAY WS)? ambiguousIdentifier typeHint? (WS? LPAREN WS? RPAREN)? (WS asTypeClause)? (WS? argDefaultValue)?
   ;

WS
   : [ \t\u000C] +
   ;
```

However when I parse the code above I get errors like:

```
line 5:14 no viable alternative at input '\nDim nstr As String\n x = Inputbox("How Happy are you"'
line 5:14 no viable alternative at input '\n x = Inputbox("How Happy are you"'
line 5:14 mismatched input '"How Happy are you"' expecting { [long list of keywords]}
line 6:16 mismatched input '"Number"' expecting {[same long list of keywords] }
line 6:26 mismatched input '"Enter any number"' expecting <EOF>
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: You don't skip whitespaces automatically? That's pretty unusual and as you can see it makes your rules less readable. What's the rational behind the decision keep WS as normal tokens?

Comment: I see, it's already in the original grammar.

Comment: I’m an ANTLR n00b   The WS was in the VB6 grammar I started off with. So my rationale was: seems to work. No clue what the rationale of the original author was. Really stuck due to my lack of understanding

Comment: Some of the grammars in the ANTLR grammar directory are of bad quality, which doesn't make it easy for beginners to use them. This grammar could use some improvements for sure.

Comment: How would I design a args identifier? It can take 1-3 arguments for the function which could be function calls or strings (I think the last one could be a number too)